# All react native class components suddenly "undefined" when attempted to render but not on console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After changing nothing all of my previously working class components cause a ComponentException. All my function components still work fine; it is only the class components that fail. The class components extend React.Component and have a render method that returns a View so I'm unsure whats wrong. I've tested on my phone as well as the iOS Simulator and both fail similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I messed up a bunch of imports by changing the export in one of my most used files! My bad, I should have read the error message more carefully.